# A PHP Socket Server with Flash Clients

Tags: php, sockets

How do I implement a PHP Socket Server, I am using PHP5.

Is there a ready made framework already available for me to use instead of going into the nitty gritties of the implementation details?
Basically I want to serve Flash clients using this Socket Server and this would be running in an Apache Environment.

This is the first time I am treading into PHP territory so consider me a noob.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Zend_AMF](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.amf.introduction.html) (emphasis mine)

> Zend_Amf provides support for Adobe's » Action Message Format (AMF), to allow communication between Adobe's » Flash Player and PHP. Specifically, it provides a gateway server implementation for **handling requests sent from the Flash Player to the server** and mapping these requests to object and class methods and arbitrary callbacks.

- http://framework.zend.com/download/amf
- http://fritzthomas.com/php/zend-framework/329-zend_amf-update-and-examples/

and [AMFPHP](http://www.amfphp.org/) as an alternative.

Also, check out [PHP Socket's API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php) and check out this [IBM Article about Memory Management with PHP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/).

**Edit**
This is not server push though. PHP is not well suited for long running processes. If you want a push implementation, have a look at [*Comet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technologies.

Comment: is it socket based? can the server push messages to clients, I want the clients to be always connected to the server.

Comment: Like it says: *handling requests sent from the Flash Player to the server*. PHP is not a good choice for long running processes or push services atm. Search around for *Comet*.

Comment: Since I am a noob in PHP I was just wondering why PHP is not a good choice for long running  or push services?

Comment: Because will start to leak memory when running. I have updated the anwer with an article about memory management.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Aleksey Zapparov's PHP Socket server

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/5758.html

Its very simple to hange your own code off it. But be warned that you should be careful about your memory management. If you're writing a very complex OO app, then you should definitely install the ciercular reference checking garbage collector. And, since it use socket_select() you don't want ti to be hanging around too long witing for your code to do something.

Alternatively (if you are running on anything other than a Microsoft platform) it may be simpler to hang the php process off [x]inetd and just use stdio for communications.

HTH

C.

Comment: What's it about memory management, is the class heavy on memomry, What is HTH and C?

Comment: CLients would generally be connected continuosly, is that too much to ask from PHP?

Comment: HTH = Hope that helps, C = Me, if the answer doesn't make much sense then you should go read up on PHP memory management and garbage colelction, and make sure you monitor mem usage when testing your app.